# java cannot find symbol: method toLowerCase(String)

Tags: java, string, character

I was trying to write a method named isVowel that returns whether a String is a vowel (a single-letter string containing a, e, i, o, or u, case-insensitively). Meanwhile, find there's a confliction in character and string. Now, what to do? Thank you all.

```java
public static boolean isVowel(String c)
{
    String c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
    return c=="a"||c=="e"||c=="i"||c=="o"||c=="u";

}
```

**variable c is already defined in method isVowel(String)
!!no suitable method found for toLowerCase(String)**

Comment: Why your method is taking `String` instead of `char`? What should be result if we call it like `isVowel("abc")` or `isVowel("")`?

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `String` where `Character` is expected.
If you are passing only single character in `String` then use below to convert to lowercase.

```java
public static boolean isVowel(String s)
{
    char c = Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(0));
    return c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u';
}
```

Comment: Updated answer. Use single quotes in comparison

Answer (score 1):

1. You declare an identifier `c` twice in the same method scope, as a parameter, and as a local variable, which will *not* compile;
2. Use `char` as a type of your parameter, instead of `String`, otherwise you risk to accept the string that is longer than 1 character; besides, `String` object is much heavier;
3. Generally, [almost] never compare strings with `==` operator. Use [`.equals(Object object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)), instead.

Better, cleaner and faster method design would be this:

```java
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return "aeiouAEIOU".contains(String.valueOf(c));
}
```

or even better:

```java
public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    return "aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c)!=-1;
}
```

`indexOf(int char)` [returns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) `-1`, if `char` is not found.

Comment: "try not to compare strings with `==`" should really be "*don't* compare strings with `==`"

Comment: Well.. string pool is there.. and that's why I deliberately said "try not to".. as I don't know, maybe in some cases, OP would have a design, where more performant code will be relying on the string pool references.